# Type casting and Comparison with Loose Operator "=="

Tags: php, casting, comparison

I have a problem baffling me terribly. I noticed this before but didn't give it any heed until today.
I was trying to write my own check for integer strings. I know of `is_numeric()` but it does not suffice since it counts `float` as numeric not only `integers` and `is_int()` which does not work on string numbers.

I did something similar to this

```
$var1 = 'string';
$var2 = '123'; 

var_dump( (int)$var1 == $var1);// boolean true 
var_dump((int)$var2 == $var2);// boolean true

 var_dump((int)$var1);//int 0
 var_dump($var1);//string 'string' (length=6)
```

As expected the second var dump outputs true since I expect with php's loose comparison that the string and integer versions be equal.

However with the first, I don't get why this is so. I have tried casting to `bool` and it still gives me the same result.

I have tried assigning the cast var to a new variablr and comparing the two, still the same result

Is this something I am doing wrong or it is a php bug?

***Note 
I am not comparing types here. I'm actually trying to take advantage of the fact that `int 0` is not equal to `string 'string'`.

I wrote my integer check differently so I don't really need alternatives for that.

***Edit
I did some extra checking and it turns out that `0 == 'string'` is true as well. How is that possible?

***Edit 2 
There are multiple correct answers below to the question. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: What happens if you use "==="?

Comment: var_dump((int)$var1) returns "int(0)" for me.

Comment: @Jim, I knew I should have added that. Well it obviously outputs false. But I'm not comparing types as I already stated. I am trying to take advantage of the behaviour of == operator

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895421/42223

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a *feature*. Any string can be casted to an integer, but [the cast will return 0 if the string doesn't start with an integer value.](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) Also, when comparing an integer and a string, [the string is casted to an integer and then the check is done against the two integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Because of that rule, about just any random string is "equal" to zero. (To bypass this behavior, you should use [`strcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php), as it performs an explicit string comparison by casting anything passed to a string.)

To make sure I'm dealing with an integer, I would use `is_numeric` first, then convert the string to an `int`, and verify that the stringified int corresponds to the input value.

```
if (is_numeric($value) && strcmp((int)$value, $value) == 0)
{
    // $value is an integer value represented as a string
}
```

Comment: If `$value` is bigger than the maximum int size, then PHP will use the max int size, and then `strcmp((int)$value, $value) != 0`. This could be considered a feature or a bug with respect to the function -- anyone using the above should be aware of it though and prepare appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

According to php.net http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php:

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
```

So, I think it is juggling the types, and actually casting both sides to int. Then comparing either the sum of the ascii values or the ascii values of each respective index in the string.

Comment: I didn't. I'm typing from mobile and that's a lot of typing for me. Secondly, that's what my vardump outputs. Maybe its due to xdebug.

Comment: Sorry. Above was not for you.
I knew the behaviour was strange but mostly forgot this aspect of it but forgot this aspect when I tried to rely on it. Now I have lots of right answers on my hands. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all in mathematices '=' is called transitive b/c (A=B and B=C => A=C) is valid.

This is not the case with PHPs "=="!

```
(int)$var1 == $var1
```

In that case PHP will cast 'string' to 0 -  that's a convention.

Then ==-operator will implicitely have the second operand 'string' also be casted to integer -> as well 0.

That leads to true.

Comment: +1: For mentioning transitivity, I always bring this up when ranting about PHP comparisons as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You made an error with your post, the correct output is this:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
int(0)
string(6) "string"
```

What happens is this:

1. Because you cast the variable to an integer, and you compare it to an integer with a loose comparison `==`, PHP will first implicitely cast the string to an integer, a more explicit but 100% equivalent form would be: `if((int)$var1 == (int) $var1)`
2. See 1), the same thing applies here
3. It prints `int(0)`, as it should, because it fails to parse the number, it will return `0` instead.
4. Prints `string(6) "string"` - as expected

Comment: I didn't. I'm typing from mobile and that's a lot of typing for me. Secondly, that's what my vardump outputs. Maybe its due to xdebug.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, maybe you just mixed them up somehow, I'm sure xdebug doesn't change it ;)

Comment: funny enough that's what appears in my browser window. Exactly as I typed. I just crosschecked

Comment: I think it is xdebug doing it. It looks different from my old laptop which doesn't have xdebug installed. array dumps look really good too

Comment: I just realized you were referring to the order of the outputs, I was thinking it was the format of the outputs. Crazy how a young stubborn mind thinks. I fixed it now.

Comment: @frostymarvelous 5 years later and you came back to that? Wow!

Comment: 5 more years have gone by and SO brought me back.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** This answer is in response to [a related question about the Twig template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890399/why-is-this-twig-statement-behaving-weird), that was marked as a duplicate, and redirects here.
>
> Because the context is different, this answer is provided to those members of the SO community who may benefit from additional details specifically related to [twig](/questions/tagged/twig) exclusively.
>
> **TL;DR**: see this post [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

### Problem

#### Context

- Twig template engine (latest version as of Fri 2017-01-27T05:12:25)

#### Scenario

- DeveloperYlohEnrohK uses comparison operator in twig expression
- DeveloperYlohEnrohK notices unexpected results when using equality comparison operator

#### Questions

- Why does the equality comparison operator (`==`) produce unexpected results in Twig?
- Why do the following produce different results?

  ```
  {{ dump(0 == 'somekey') }}          ==> true
  {{ dump(0|lower == 'somekey') }}    ==> false
  ```

### Solution

- Since Twig is based on PHP, the [casting](/questions/tagged/casting), implicit [type-conversion](/questions/tagged/type-conversion) and [comparison](/questions/tagged/comparison) semantics of PHP apply to Twig templates as well.
- Unless DeveloperYlohEnrohK is intentionally and specifically leveraging the behavior of implicit type-conversion in PHP, the comparison expression will almost certainly produce counterintuitive and unexpected results.
- This is a [well-known circumstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646) that is described in detail [in this SO post on PHP equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646).
- **Solution:** Just as is the case with standard PHP, unless the [well-known circumstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646) is accounted for, using `===` in Twig is much less likely to produce unexpected results.

### Pitfalls

- As of this writing, the Twig template engine does not support `===` in the same way as standard PHP
- Twig does have a substitute for `===` [using `same as`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html)
- Because of this, the treatment of this [well-known circumstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646) differs slightly between PHP and Twig.

### See also

- [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)
- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare types of variables too you should use `===`.

Comment: My understanding was that OP wanted to check stuff like `"555" == 555`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that more rigorously tests for either an int or an integer string.

```
function isIntegerNumeric($val) {
  return (
    is_int($val)
      || (
        !is_float($val)
          && is_numeric($val)
          && strpos($val, ".") === false
      )
  );
}
```

It's relatively quick and avoids doing any string checking if it doesn't have to.