# Why is this twig statement behaving weird?

Tags: php, twig

I just run in a weird behaviour in twig.

I've just used a `for()` over an array that hasn't any keys set but one, which was added into the array before. For test cases, just assume this php array:

```
$array = array (
    0 => 'test1',
    1 => 'test2',
    'someKey' => 'test3'
)
```

So, I did this in twig:

```
{% for key, value in array %}
    {% if key == 'someKey' %}
        {{ 'something special happend' }}
    {% else %}
        {{ 'how boring' }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What totally caught me off-guard was the fact, that `something special happend` has been called **twice**.

After some searching I've found that this case was also true for the key `0`.

So I tried following:

```
{{ dump (key == 'someKey') }}
```

The result was

1. true
2. false
3. true

So I did another test:

```
{{ dump(key|lower == 'somekey') }}
```

The result was

1. false
2. false
3. true

Since I wanted to be sure, this was my last test

```
{{ dump(0 == 'somekey') }}
{{ dump(0|lower == 'somekey') }}
```

The result was

1. true
2. false

Why is this behaviour like it is? I can't explain it.

PS: I know by know that I can use the [same as](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html) operator, but I'm just curious how this works.

Comment: `{% if key == 'someKey' $}` is this a typo ? it should be `{% if key == 'someKey' %}`

Comment: @Himal yeah, was a typo, thanks for pointing that out. fixed it

Comment: About your last test (all really...): In the first case you compare an integer to a string which will be cast to `0` as it does not begin with a number and in the second case you compare 2 strings.

Comment: @jeroen I didn't know about the integer casting of strings. That's good to know. Thank you, sir!

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895421/42223